# Spring Integration TCP - I have requirement to use Spring for Non-Spring TCP Server

Tags: spring-integration

Spring-Integration , TCP Serve will push Packet to my Application and once packet received  will send Ack to server.    At last send final response once after processing done. I have to keep connection open until packet processed. I am new

Please help.

Comment: What have you tried to achieve your wanted result? Please provide code and specify a problem.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need to use a `TcpInboundGateway` with the `TcpNetClientConnectionFactory`: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/5.0.7.RELEASE/reference/html/ip.html#tcp-connection-factories

Comment: OK. As people say: you need to share some code you tried so far, what expectations and what the problem you get from there. Otherwise it's impossible to help you.